# How to I update a table column with a Join in Teradata?

Tags: join, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following two tables:

Transaction_table:

| Date | SSN | Cust_Num | Cust_Ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 111-1111 | null | null |
| 1/2/21 | 222-2222 | null | null |
| 1/3/21 | null | null | null |

Customer_table:

| Date | SSN | Cust_Num | Cust_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 111-1111 | 101 | Adam |
| 1/2/21 | 222-2222 | 102 | Bobby |
| 1/3/21 | 333-3333 | 103 | Carter |

How do I update the Cust_Num on the Transaction_table with the Cust_Num on the Customer_table when the SSN on both table equal each other?  Additionally, how do I update the Cust_Ind to ‘SSN Match’ when SSN on both table equal each other?  Thank you!

I tried the following code and received errors:

Update t
from Transaction_table as t,
Customer_table as src

set t.Cust_Num = src.Cust_Num,
t.Cust_ind = 'SSN_Match'

where t.SSN = src.SSN

Comment: In Teradata, the left-hand side of the SET must be unqualified. You don't need a qualification anyway, since it has to be a column name in the target table.

Comment: For future reference, please include any error messages you receive.